# SharePoint Retention Policy for Archiving

Tags: sharepoint-online, retention, drop-off-library, document-archiving

Can you set a retention policy to move a whole custom content type (based on document set, with documents inside) to different drop off locations and leaving a shortcut behind?

Also, will a drop off library every face the 5K limit, and do the short cuts left behind in the original location still count as part of the 5K limit?

Answer (score 1):

One of my favourite bloggers has a post titled [How to set up retention and deletion policies for files and folders in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/set-retention-deletion-policies-files-folders-sharepoint/) which I think would be worth your time to read.

To answer one of your questions "`...leaving a shortcut behind`": yes, this is possible, it is known as 'In-place Records Management', the final section in this [MS post](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Implement-Records-Management-0bfe419e-eb1d-421a-becd-5be9fed1e479) will help you somewhat.  He is a screen-shot of how it looks in SP (note - my screenshot is of a Library-based Policy, rather than a Content Type-based Policy.  If the menu looks a little different, that is why).

[image: Information Management Policy]

Regarding your question on Drop-Off Libraries, [this post](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-content-organizer-rules-to-route-documents-1e4d37a3-635d-4764-b0fc-f7c5356c1900) has some info on how they work.  I've not used these or read all of the post, but I understand the principle.  I've used Information Management Policies - I imagine that you want to be able to configure a Policy to transfer a document to different location (a Drop Off Library) once certain conditions have been met e.g. 3 years after Creation Date.  It looks like that would be possible, as you see in the picture above.

Comment: Hi Tally thank  you for that. So if I set the retention on the content type, all the items in that document set will be archived, correct ? (assuming the content type is a document set or customisation of) - and when this retention policy is set to leave a link behind, does ths link count as one of the 5K limit in the sharepoint document library or not really?

Comment: I have not archived Document Sets or used a Drop-Off Library for archiving, so I would recommend testing it.  I approached Information Management differently.  For the 'Action', instead of moving the document, I made SP automatically create a review task (I believe I used an OOTB Disposition Workflow for this).  Regarding the 5k limit, I don't know I'm afraid - you could post a separate question on that specifically.